# Using と to mark a question

Tags: dialects, particle-と, questions, spoken-language

I've been working on listening practice again.  This time, I'm watching the first episode of an anime series called スケッチブック 〜full color's〜.

In the first episode, a certain character asks three questions, and I think all three end with `と`.  I recorded them and [uploaded an MP3](http://sandwich.quarplet.com/sora.mp3), and I attempted to transcribe them:

> 1. あっ、空{そら}！　どこいくとー？
> 2. 空、何探しよーと？
> 3. 空、どうしたとー？

Here are my questions:

- Is `と` a dialect equivalent of using `の` to mark a question?
- Am I just hearing `と` wrong?

(I'm sorry if the whole transcription is wrong!  I'm not very good at hearing Japanese yet.)

Comment: 博多弁っぽいね・・http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%9A%E5%A4%9A%E5%BC%81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former. と can be used to mark questions in [九州方言{きゅうしゅうほうげん}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B9%9D%E5%B7%9E%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80) (in this case, she is speaking in [博多弁{はかたべん}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%9A%E5%A4%9A%E5%BC%81), a subdialect). (More technically, it is a 準体助詞{じゅんたいじょし} like の, and shares the nominalization property, which is probably why it can be used to mark questions like that.)

Comment: People talk that way down here in Kumamoto as well..

Comment: @ssb, well indeed, as it is part of Kyuushuu after all!

Comment: I guess what I mean to ask is if there's anything specific about this that makes it Hakata-ben rather than an ambiguous Kyushu dialect

Comment: @ssb Not from the provided clip, no, I don't think. I downloaded an episode of the anime to figure out which one it was. I'm not sure how Chocolate figured it out from the clip.

Comment: スイマセン！たまたま「博多弁っぽいかな～」って思っただけです～私は関西人なので、博多弁・熊本弁・他の九州弁の区別はつかないと思います。(でも九州の人はだいたい分かるんだそうです。)

Comment: @Chocolate なるほどですね。まあ、どちらしても結局博多弁だったので、凄く感がいいと思います。

Comment: The verb ending ~よう is specific to the northern parts of Kyushu, mainly Hakata and Kitakyushu, but it is also heard in Oita. In Kumamoto, the second question above would be:

空、何しよると？